# Best way to load long image list in Flutter

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I have a `ListView` for load a list of images using [advanced network image plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage) like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: parseURLImageFromService(productImageURL),
      height: screen.width * ratio,
      placeholder: Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
            CompanyColors.green[500],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      errorWidget: defaultLogoImage(screen, ratio),
      width: screen.width * (ratio * 0.75),
    );
  }
}
```

But when i render the app, all image try to load at the same time, i would like to load the images ony by one waiting the previous.

Comment: use Listview.builder it will only load the images that are visible as you start scrolling it will load the next images.

Comment: another workaround is - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509349/10269042

Comment: The problem is the images take much time to load, i don't know why ...

Comment: Try to use FadeinImage Widget instead of CachedNetworkImage

Comment: With FadeInImage can't catch error in the fetching process of the image

Comment: Is it slow when you're using listview.builder? You sure its a flutter issue then?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this, but the solution isn't related with Flutter. The main problem is the size of the images and the network speed of download, I solve this adding a function on the backend, that function resize the image when it's uploaded. So when I display the list of image I use the miniature image and when the user open the details I load the original size image.