# How to pagination with infinite_scroll_pagination flutter

Tags: flutter, api, pagination, widget

```
 List<Event> events = [];
  int currentPage = 1;
  Dio dio = Dio();

  void getEvents() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await Dio().get('http://52.90.175.175/api/events/get?page=$currentPage');
      var data = response.data["data"]["data"] as List;
      setState(() {
        events = data.map((i) => Event.fromJson(i)).toList();
      });

      print(events);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This is how I fetch my events and 10 events per page is loading and here is my json response of API

[image]

[my full json](https://justpaste.it/btltj)

Next page URL and next page decide by API and I want to know how to pagination with [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)  for my widget

```
 ListView.builder(
            itemCount: events.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                title: Text(events[index].title),
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(events[index].description),
                    Text("${events[index].start} - ${events[index].end}"),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776613/pagination-with-listview-in-flutter

Comment: try searching for the answer before creating a new one.

Comment: i am new to flutter i don't understand the answer please can you show me example for my case I am a student I provide my tried code above

Answer (score 0):

no need to add any packages, add this code to initState

```
controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
```

and create this method.

```
_scrollListener() {
    print(controller.position.extentAfter);
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
      currentPage++;
      getEvents();
    }
  }
```

Comment: where should i call this method

Comment: no need to call manually when the scroll will reach to end it will be automatically called by the scroll controller.