# How can i paginate ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter

I am deploying a social media mobile app and last thing i have to do is pagination. I looked at various flutter blogs etc and i tried to figure it out but i had tons of errors when i tried those codes (i could not figure out the way to implement them with my codes unfortunately.)

What i want is basically, when i scroll down after various number of posts (for example 5 posts), my flutter app will initiate a function like reload more and give me more posts.How can i do it?

```
Future<List<Post>> FetchPosts(http.Client client) async {
  List<Post> posts;
  List<Post> finalposts;
  final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json");
  final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  posts = parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJSON(json)).toList();
  return posts;
}

class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget{...}

class FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  FeedScreenState({Key key, this.posts});
  final List<Post> posts;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: refreshpage,
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
          future: FetchPosts(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData ?
            PostsList(posts: snapshot.data,user:user)
                : Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.pink,valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pinkAccent),
              ),);},),),);}}

class PostsList extends StatefulWidget{...}

class PostsListState extends State<PostsList> {
  final List<Post> posts;
  PostsListState({Key key, this.posts, this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return AspectRatio(...);
      },);}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in this answer: [Flutter ListView lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508322/flutter-listview-lazy-loading) you can listen to a `ScrollController` and fetch more posts according to the `ScrollPosition`

Comment: it looks like functioning,but it does not take posts from json but generates it itself.I need a function where it takes it from json like i did in "fetchposts"

Comment: @umarbeyoglu why don't you add "fetchposts" inside the scroll listener and refresh your list inside a setState

Comment: Done.Lastly,how can i configure the function such that it loads only 3 posts per fetch?

Comment: You can configure your API to accept option to load specific number of posts.

Comment: no,my api is stricted in that way. I only need to do this in backend (as flutter&dart)

Comment: no you most probably will need to modify your server to accommodate lazily loading to load different sets of posts each time it needs to fetch.