# how to load data from an API inside a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

im obtaining a list o news from an API,im using a ListView.builder to show the data...

the problem comes when i tried to scroll down or up in the list, because previously loaded data is not kept and if  i scroll-down to fast the same error happends...

i tried to use in my statefull widget a mixin "AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin" but does not works.

```
class _NewsPageState extends State<NewsPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {


and i tried to change the build method according to another solution proposed here

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
```

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possible answers from my understanding of the question (data not loading fast enough)

1. Store data locally in a `List<Widget>` then pass it to the `ListView.builder.`
2. Set `shrinkWrap` in the `ListView.builder` to false if you want the data to persist for scrolling
3. If you want the list data to load from the internet while scrolling, you can try `ScrollController`
   Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508322/flutter-listview-lazy-loading) for more on that regard.

Comment: the data persist but the next problem is when i scroll-down fast the app froze and return this error   **HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404**

Comment: It is confirmed. when scroll-down slowly i can go to the last result without problem.

Comment: @juanfgarcia if you haven't, try having a placeholder there like a loading circle before the HTTP request finishes. There are examples in the link above