# How to load Images Effectively in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, dart

I have a flutter app that has a screen where I am displaying a number of different images using a ListView.Builder(). I ask the user to select the images either locally or through social media platforms and after the user selects the images they go on to the image display screen where I will be displaying the images in a ListView.Builder().
The app works fine for certain number of images, but when the number of images increases the image display screen tends to hang and often times just CRASH !!.
I have looked at ways to solve this and came across the cacheWidth and cacheHeight properties, but when I use the properties the images do not look original but instead looks either stretched, and is off dimensions (Most of the images).I also have an isolate that runs in the background which uploads the images to firestorage.
What could be the actual problem, is it the images due to which memory leak is happening or is it because of something else ?

Comment: You can refer this link, it maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508322/flutter-listview-lazy-loading

Comment: Thank You @RamGupta will look into it !!